# Possible to use Php's mail() function to send 1 million plus mails?

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer, spam

I was wondering if it would be feasible to send over 1 million emails (stored in an array or some sql database) using php's mail function. Is this farfetched. I'm new to php and curious of the function's limitations. Thank you so much! I'm not looking to necessarily use a SMTP service like MailChimp at this point.

Comment: ideally you should batch send these high number of emails over multiple days or even multiple weeks when using `mail()` or most common known PHPMailer class ... 
Hosting providers can have hard settings on **account level** which might block sending emails if you trying to send more then 100 per second for example It all depends on SMTP server (mail server) configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but no.

Most likely your IP will be blocked before reaching the 1000 mark. Consider using a service like mailgun or sendgrid

Comment: I dont think so. Take f.ex gmail. They block you if you are a new sender and suddendly send a heck of a lot of mail

Comment: hosting providers can have hard settings on **account level** which also might block sending emails if you trying to send more then 100 per second for example It all depends on SMTP server (mail server) configuration... But 1 million is alot off emails ideally the topicstarter should batch send these number of emails over multiple days or even multiple weeks..

Comment: Agreed, i know of the webhost limiting as i sell webhosting myself